# Can we insert Image and TextView in List Item

Tags: android, listview

I'm working on the project in which i have a listview and i want to insert image and text in every item of the List. 
I know ho to do make list item react but i dont know how to add image or fragment in the listview item .

Comment: yes you can. Just google it.

Comment: i mean by code not in xml !

Comment: yes, both ways are doable

Comment: can you post any example ??

Comment: i think it is done by view holder but i don't have any idea about implementation

Comment: there is a good tutorial for doing so. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

1. create a custom layout for your list item
2. create a custom list adapter
3. set ListAdapter to custom Adapter`

   ```
    public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;

   public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
       super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

       this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

      View view=convertView;

      if (convertView==null){view = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitem_birthday, parent,false);}

       TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    //set textview text

       ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

     //set image resource


       return view;
   }

   }
   ```

in your ListActivity use this code to set the adapter :

```
   CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: then how i will be able to bind the adabter in listactivity